# Check Duplicate Value in array javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to check to 1 array value, if value duplicated, it will pop up alert.
Here is the function :

```
function checkDuplicateTenure(){
    var f = document.frmPL0002;
    var supplgrid = document.getElementById("mdrPymtGrid2");  
    var len = (supplgrid.rows.length) - 1;

    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        if (f.cbo_loanTenure[i+1].value == f.cbo_loanTenure[i].value) {
            alert("DUPLICATE LOAN TENURE IN MONTH(S)");
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

That function is works if got duplicate value in array, but if all value is different, its will hit js error  `if (f.cbo_loanTenure[i+1].value == f.cbo_loanTenure[i].value) {` Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference.

Thanks

Comment: seems `supplgrid.rows` and `f.cbo_loanTenure` are not of the same length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple out of bounds error. Fix it by using this:

```
for (var i=0;i<len-1;i++) {
```

So, `i+1` will never be the same as `len`.

Answer (score 0):

change it

```
for(var i=0;i<len-1;i++){
        if (f.cbo_loanTenure[i+1].value == f.cbo_loanTenure[i].value) {
            alert("DUPLICATE LOAN TENURE IN MONTH(S)");
        }
    }
```

suppose your loop  runs 5 times and you can set `i+1` inside the loop it comes 6 which is undefined index that why js error occurs

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function checkDuplicateTenure(){
    var f = document.frmPL0002;
    var supplgrid = document.getElementById("mdrPymtGrid2");  
    var len = (supplgrid.rows.length) - 1;

    for(var i=0;i<len-1;i++){
        if (f.cbo_loanTenure[i+1].value == f.cbo_loanTenure[i].value) {
            alert("DUPLICATE LOAN TENURE IN MONTH(S)");
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why are you reducing length by 2? If  `supplgrid.rows` and `f.cbo_loanTenure` have the same lenght it is enough to reduce `len` only once, that was done already.